# Listing files by last accessed time?

Tags: ls

How can I list files according to the last time they were accessed?

So far I haven't seen a command that can list them by time.

I need it to display files that have been last accessed last December, if that helps any.

Comment: Hang on, do you really mean _access_ or _modification_ time?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this is possible. In theory both `ls` and `find` are quite capable of sorting or finding by access time. The problem is that since kernel version 2.3.60, the default options for filesystem mounting include `noatime`:

```
   noatime
          Do not update inode access  times  on  this  filesystem
          (e.g.,  for faster access on the news spool to speed up
          news servers).
```

If your disks are mounted using the default options, the access time will not be modified when a file is accessed so the information you need to find by access time will not be present on your system. See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/19892/22222) question on U&L.SE for more information.

Comment: Looks like you're right, I pulled up an outdated VM to try it on. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @nerdwaller no worries, I was about to upvote you when I tested and saw id did not work. I was intrigued enough to go look up why :).