# Is there any way to tell the last time a memory card was viewed?

Tags: memory, privacy

I accidentally left memory card at friends house and wanted to know if they viewed my pics!

Comment: Would you feel better to have your suspicions confirmed? Pound to a penny, they did.

Comment: Assuming that you are able to see that they did, what will you do with the information? Maybe they just found a memory card on the table, thought "huh, I thought they were all put away safely" and looked to see what was on it to see if it was something they were still intending to copy to their computer?

Comment: It depends which file-system you have on your card and what operating system we're talking about.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Listing files by last accessed time?](http://superuser.com/questions/584081/listing-files-by-last-accessed-time)

Comment: What specific type of memory card? What operating system and or hardware do you access the card with? Does your friend use a different operating system?

Comment: It's a Kodak 16 gb SD card....and I use windows 7

Answer (score 3):

This is not generally possible. It's possible to mount the memory card in read-only mode, which would not result in any changes.

Depending on the file system and the mount options, you may be able to view last-accessed times. In Windows Explorer, right click on the file and select Properties, and you'll see Last Accessed. But again, this is not a guarantee. The files may have been accessed without updating that value.

Comment: Agreed, notoriously unreliable!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/254438/lastaccess-time-is-incorrect

Comment: The thing about file systems is that it is up to the operating system to update that information.

Comment: Wouldn't the "last accessed" timestamp be updated when Explorer (or any other file manager) builds thumbnails for the images, which is often done? In that case, looking at the value of "last accessed" could very well be completely meaningless.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling - I don't believe that date is updated simply by viewing the contents of a folder.  They would have to perform a file operation ( copy, open, etc ) for that to happen.  Even then they could in theory use a operating system other then Windows.

Comment: @Ramhound I wasn't talking about the viewing folder contents (akin to issuing a "dir" command in a command prompt window) but rather when the file manager (on Windows and in the most common case, Explorer) reads the files in order to generate thumbnails.